# Image creation from pdf

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, imagemagick

I am creating a cron job in which I copy files from one directroy to another. The cron job works fine it copies the files to the import directory. The structure of import directory is like this.

```
import
      folder1
          pdf_file1
      folder2
          pdf_file2
```

I am trying to create a thumbnail image for each pdf file that is copied to the folders, I installed ImageMagik and my php code to create a thumnail image  is

```
 if ($preview != "") {
    $copy_res = ftp_get("files/upload/" . $ftp_upload["path"] . "/" . $preview, "files/import/" . $ftp_upload["preview"] . "/" . $preview);
    $md5_checksum = md5("files/import/" . $ftp_upload["path"] . "/" . $preview);
 } else {
         //$pdf_file = 'files/import/folder1/pdf_file1';
         $pdf_file = 'files/import/' . $ftp_upload["path"]."/".$filename_new;
         if (file_exists($pdf_file)){
             echo 'I am here';
             exec("convert -density 300 " . $pdf_file . "[0]" . $filename_new . ".jpg");
         }
 }
```

When I run the code it comes to the else statement and echo the line but its not executing the exec command.
I checked the convert command from Command Prompt for that I navigated to

```
 C:\wamp\www\project\files\import\folder1
```

and then I run this command

```
 exec("convert -density 300  test.pdf[0]  test.jpg");
```

From the command prompt it worked but in my code it s not working .
Is there any issue with the path ? because the file is alreday copied when I try to create the thumbnail for it.

The ImageMagik is installed in

```
 C:\Program Files(x86)\ImageMagik
```

Any ideas what I am doing wron ? and is there any other faster way to create thumbail image for pdf ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a missing space that separates the path to the `pdf` file and the new name for the image file.

```
exec("convert -density 300 " . $pdf_file . "[0]" . $filename_new . ".jpg");
```

Should be:

```
exec("convert -density 300 " . $pdf_file . "[0] " . $filename_new . ".jpg");
-----------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: still not working its not giving any error all it do is just skipping the exec command :(

Comment: @FaryalKhan `exec()` can return the output of the command you supply. Try to see if there's any error in the output. http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: You were right it was the space problem :) working now but can you please tell me what if I want to make a thumbnail image of 300x400 what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

I now write my code seperating the code form the exec() so that you can display the information you are sending to Imagemagick.
I would also try setting the filenames outside the exec()

```
$input = $pdf_file . "[0]";
$output = $filename_new . ".jpg"
$cmd = " -density 300 $input -thumbnail 200x300 $output ";
// echo $cmd."<br>";
exec("convert $cmd");
```

Added a resize but it will keep the image proportions - if you need an exact size you could crop the image or pad it with a colour.

Comment: i need a thumbnail image of 200x300 size?